# Data disappears from master Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, preference-center

We have a master DE that we use to select records and to manage subscription status for newsletters (a boolean True/False for each one)... we've seen records simply vanish from the master DE and we don't understand why.

We had one record today where the customer complained that they can't unsubscribe... we couldn't find the record in our master DE (which can sometimes happen - customer signs up from one address but they provide a different one) but the client sent us the email they received.

When we click on the unsubscribe link we're taken to our custom preference centre and the record is there... which is strange since we can't query the DE to find the record.  In any case, we change the boolean to `FALSE` and now we can see the record in the DE.

Anyone seen something like this before?

Comment: Never see. Vanishing records. Is this a sendable DE. Are you using contact delete?

Comment: Does your master DE have data retention enabled? If so, the DE may be deleting records on its own after a specified period of time. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_manage_de_policies.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Comment: I suspect on your `Custom` preference center page... And there seems to be code[AMPscript/SSJS]  which is made to add/delete rows as above!

Comment: @eazyE - we don't use any "contact delete" activities
Also, ropedog - we don't use data retention 
Finally, VishalKumarCV - not sure I follow... the PC page only pulls in what is contained in the master DE

Comment: What have you done to verify that they 'vanish'? From the sound of it, the contact still exists (there on preference center), you just cannot find it in the DE. To that point, maybe it is something more inside your searching/investigation that is causing this and less that the record actually disappears. Also, where does your pref center pull from? All subs or the DE? More info will be needed for us to help debug if it is not any of the above

Comment: The data comes from a 'master' data extension, not from All Subs.  We can't find the record when we search it using SQL... comes up blank, and it's a very basic query that we're running so I'm perplexed.

Comment: Have you tried using a filter or exporting it to a csv to look through?  Have you verified that there are no hidden characters or spacings in the data that may be causing the disconnect? Try doing something like `WHERE EmailAddress LIKE '%blah@blah.com%'`? If the data is there in pref center lookup, then the record must still exist there or the pref center would fail.